# Change animation for different states in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation

I have the following CSS animations that are applied when transitioning states in my AngularJS app:

```
.content.ng-enter,
.content.ng-leave
{
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 350ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-duration: 350ms;
}
.content.ng-leave
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-animation-name: slideouttoleft;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-animation-name: slideouttoleft;
}
.content.ng-enter
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-animation-name: slideinfromright;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-animation-name: slideinfromright;
}
.content.ng-leave.reverse
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-animation-name: slideouttoright;
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -moz-animation-name: slideouttoright;
}
.content.ng-enter.reverse
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-animation-name: slideinfromleft;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-animation-name: slideinfromleft;
}
```

So when moving from one section to another, the content slides from left to right. However for certain navigation's I want to make it so that it slides the other way... I can't just apply it to a button as I also want to tie it up to the browser back and forward buttons, so it needs to apply to the actual state.

So let's say I have three states:

Section 1, Section 2, Section 3.

Moving from 1 to 2 or 3 uses the normal animation, but moving from 3 to 2, or 2 to 1 uses the reverse animation. If that makes sense?

How could I tie up the animations to follow this?

I do have the current state as a class on the body tag like:

`<body ng-class="{ section1 : $state.includes('section1'), section2 : $state.includes('section2'), section3 : $state.includes('section3') }">` so wonder if I could use this to apply it... Though I think it's more a case of knowing what the current state is and what the next state is and then applying a class then.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have got so far that works really well:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart",   function(evt, to, toP, from, fromP)      
{
    $('html').removeClass('goLeft').removeClass('goRight');

    if( to.name == 'section1' && from.name == 'section2' || to.name == 'section1' && from.name == 'section3' )
    {
        // go left
        $('html').addClass('goLeft');
    }
    else if( to.name == 'section3' && from.name == 'section1' || to.name == 'section3' && from.name == 'section2' )
    {
        // go right
        $('html').addClass('goRight');
    }
    else if( to.name == 'section2' && from.name == 'section1' )
    {
        // go right
        $('html').addClass('goRight');
    }
    else if( to.name == 'section2' && from.name == 'section3' )
    {
        // go left
        $('html').addClass('goLeft');
    }
});
```

And then I use the prefix to use a different CSS animation:

```
[ui-view=content].ng-enter,
[ui-view=content].ng-leave
{
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .2s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-duration: .2s;
}
.goLeft [ui-view=content].ng-leave
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-animation-name: slideouttoleft;
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-animation-name: slideouttoleft;
}
.goLeft [ui-view=content].ng-enter
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-animation-name: slideinfromright;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-animation-name: slideinfromright;
}
.goRight [ui-view=content].ng-leave
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-animation-name: slideouttoright;
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -moz-animation-name: slideouttoright;
}
.goRight [ui-view=content].ng-enter
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -webkit-animation-name: slideinfromleft;
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-animation-name: slideinfromleft;
}
```

But the code is a bit nasty as I have had to write conditionals for each possible navigation path.